# Lost Sculpt Mode

Tags: sculpt

I'm a newbie...I was working just fine till I added new windows. But now I cannot change to sculpt mode. Clicking the menu at the bottom only reveals "Object Mode" but nothing else.

Comment: did you select the object you want to sculpt? if you select a camera or a light or nothing you won't be able to switch to sculpt mode

Comment: OMG haha. Thank you! Im a total newbie. I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: select the object you want to sculpt. If you select a camera or a lamp (or any non-mesh object for that matter) there won't be Sculpt mode present in the interaction modes list.